# Clion Arduino plugin: Error:Could not find Arduino SDK (set ARDUINO_SDK_PATH)

Tags: makefile

I am trying to setup CLion as my workspace for my arduino. I have installed the two Arduino plugins for CLion, generated a new sketch project, but I am getting cmake errors on opening the project.

```
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/user/project/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake:86 (message):
  Could not find Arduino SDK (set ARDUINO_SDK_PATH)!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/user/project/CMakeFiles/3.9.4/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/user/project/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

The issue is similar to this logged issue here:
https://github.com/francoiscampbell/CLionArduinoPlugin/issues/11

As a Windows 10 user, I have the Arduino SDK installed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino`

What's interesting is that the cmake file is calling the UNIX commands when it's running in this if statement:

```
    if(UNIX)
        file(GLOB SDK_PATH_HINTS /usr/share/arduino*
            /opt/local/arduino*
            /opt/arduino*
            /usr/local/share/arduino*

                )
    elseif(WIN32)
        set(SDK_PATH_HINTS "C:\\Program Files\\Arduino"
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\libraries"
            )
    endif()
```

Comment: I have the same error, even if I set it manually: set(ARDUINO_SDK_PATH C:\\Program Files\\Arduino) I checked my path, but nothing wrong in the arduino path, I'm using Cygwin if it can help...

Comment: Me too. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: unfortunately no :(